# How to abstract creation of identical methods for each attribute?

Tags: java

Let's say I wrote the following class:

```
public class Metrics {
        private static int metric1 = 0;

        public static int countMetric1() {
                metric1 += 1;
                return 0;
        }

        public static int resetMetric1() {
                int currentCount = metric1;
                metric1 = 0;
                return currentCount;
        }
}
```

I tested it and it works. But I need also to check **metric2**. Let's change the code to accommodate that.

```
public class Metrics {
        private static int metric1 = 0;
        private static int metric2 = 0;

        public static int countMetric1() {
                metric1 += 1;
                return 0;
        }

        public static int resetMetric1() {
                int currentCount = metric1;
                metric1 = 0;
                return currentCount;
        }

        public static int countMetric2() {
                metric2 += 1;
                return 0;
        }

        public static int resetMetric2() {
                int currentCount = metric2;
                metric2 = 0;
                return currentCount;
        }
}
```

Ok, nice... but definitely not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If I then want to add **metric3** or **metric4**, I'll have again to copy-paste a lot and that's [smelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Is there any way, in Java to refactor this so to avoid repetition and maintain the "staticness" of the code? (Because of the context of the code, things **have to be** static)

Extra: if this is not possible in Java, is it possible in any other language?

**Note 1:** This is **example** code. So no need to fuss over variable names.

**Note 2:** Any suggestion on how to improve the title of the question would be nice. :)

Comment: You know what is smelly aswell? Having attributes `metric1`, `metric2`, `metric3`, ... This seems to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you actually trying to solve? If you do not want to write getters and setters, take a look at [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) (caution: Project lombok uses byte code manipulation).

Comment: Why do these metrics have to be static?

Comment: If you don't want a separate field for each metric, why not use a map (possibly with an enum key)? You would then have a single `count` and `reset` method that accepts an extra enum parameter.

Comment: Instead of trying to group all your metrics into one class, how about a class called Counter(seems like this is what you are after) that has a count, name, and some public methods for incrementing/resetting? You could create n instances of the class, and keep them in a collection.

Comment: @Turing85 not to mention how smelly having **static** attributes `metric1`, `metric2`, `metric3` is...

Comment: Edited the question, considering your comments: 1) This is example code, obviously I'm not using these variable names in production. :P 2) I get your complaints about static attributes and methods but because of the context the code is in, things **have to be** static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to create a Metric class:

```
public class Metric {

    private int count = 0;
    private final String name;


    public Metric(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Metric{name='%s', count=%d}", name, count);
    }

    public int count() {
        return ++count;
    }

    public void reset() {
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

In your class, you would assign it like this:

```
private Metric someMetric = new Metric("Whatever you want to measure");
```

---

Since you seem to prefer something with static access, how about a simple Map?

```
public class Metrics {

    private static Map<String, Integer> metricsMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static int countMetric(String metric) {
        int newValue = metricsMap.compute(metric, 
                                          (s, value) -> value == null 
                                          ? 1 : value + 1);
        return newValue - 1 /* old value */;
    }

    public static void resetMetric(String metric){
        metricsMap.remove(metric);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. It has the disadvantage of losing the "staticness" of the code, though. :) (already edited the question, reflecting this fact)

Comment: @LLCampos true, but I'm not sure I see that as a disadvantage.

Comment: @LLCampos added a more static alternative